# Unable to update cocoapods 0.39 to the latest version in Xcode 8.2.1?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

```
a0007988:multipurposenavigation-showcase-ios amospune$ pod install
[!] Unable to load a specification for the plugin `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.1`
Cloning spec repo `allianz-ghe-onemobile-library-podspecs-ios` from `https://api-dev.allianz.de/ghe/onemobile-library/podspecs-ios.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://api-dev.allianz.de/ghe/onemobile-library/podspecs-ios.git` named `allianz-ghe-onemobile-library-podspecs-ios`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

This is the error, I'm getting when I try to install pod. My .xcworkspace project is present in the directory

> "/Users/AmosPune/Desktop/ios"

. Any help would be appreciated. Also when I use the command `sudo gem install pod`, it gives me this error:

```
a0007988:multipurposenavigation-showcase-ios amospune$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/pod
```

Comment: did u try with pod update

Comment: try this cmd          " sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods"

Comment: Yes, I did try 'pod update' but it doesn't work either.